# Should F# functions be placed in modules, classes, or another structure?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm starting to code in F# and am calling functions from functions with functions as parameters - there are plenty of learning resources online.  Now I am trying to put together the pieces into something more than just a collection of functions. Unfortunately I'm not finding many resources dealing with structure, design, or even how the 'bits' tie together.

I've found the `namespace` keyword (e.g. `namespace MyOnlyNamespace`) but I get a compiler error on the functions that I've placed inside the namespace:

> Namespaces cannot contain values. Consider using a module to hold your value declarations.

When I add `module CoolFunctions` I get

> Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token

So I have a multi-part question (but please answer any part that you can)

- What is a module?
- Is it like a class (something like a VB.NET module) or is it something else altogether?
- If something else, then are there classes in F#?
- Are there other structures that I should be using instead?
- How do I declare a module?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To give some specific recommendations about choosing between namespaces, modules abd classes in F#:

- If you're writing functions using `let` that are expected to be used from F#, then putting them inside a module is the best choice. This gives you API similar to `List.map` and other basic F# functions.

  Regarding naming, you should use `camelCase` unless you expect C# users to call the functions too. In that case, you should use `PascalCase` (and note that module will be compiled to a static class).
- If you're writing type delcarations, then these should generally be placed in a namespace. They are allowed inside modules too, but then they'll be compiled as nested classes.
- If you're writing F# classes, then they should be placed in namespaces too. In generall, if you're writing F# code that will be called by C#, then using classes is the best mechanism as you get full control of what the user will see (F# class is compiled to just a class).

If you have a file, it can either start with `namespace Foo.Bar` or `module Foo.Bar`, which places all code in the file inside a namespace or a module. You can always nest more modules inside this top-level declaration. A common pattern is to start with a single `namespace` and then include some type and module declarations in the file:

```
namespace MyLibrary

type SomeType = 
  // ...

module SomeFuncs = 
  let operation (st:SomeType) = // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just noting that the [F# Component Design Guidelines](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf) advise to use standard .NET naming convention - that is, PascalCase for types, methods and namespaces, and camelCase for parameters and local variables.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Yes, the recommendned naming for types/members is quite clear. The case with `let` bound values is not that clear. The F# Component Guidelines recommendation says _camelCase …or… PascalCase_ with a note _let-bound values are often public
when following traditional functional design patterns. However, generally use PascalCase when the identifier can be used from other
.NET languages._

Comment: As an alternative for public C#/VB.Net-facing values of F# modules, you may use camelCase combined with [<CompiledName("PascalCase")>] ;)

Comment: What about placement of top level modules within namespaces? I thought the rule of thumb was that a top level module should reflect the name of the file containing the code. Where do namespaces fit in here?

Answer (score 6):

concerning the **design** of F# components there is a very good [draft online](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/fsharp-component-design-guidelines.pdf).

JPalmer allready pointed you to the syntay problems but I think some other questions deserve more:

> What is a module?

Yes JPalmer is right - modules are compiled into static classes but do we really care inside F#?
IMHO you should use more modules than classes when programming in F#.
In OOP you define your classes and the methods within.
In FP you define simple types (without behaviour) and a bunch of functions to transform them. And the natural place to collect those functions is the module.

> Is it like a class (something like a VB.NET module) or is it
>   something else altogether?

A VB module is indeed a good comparision.

> If something else, then are there classes in F#?

Yes you can use classes in F# - it's a complete .net languague and .net is OOP. You can do practically everything in F# you could do in C# of VB.net (only certain cases generic constraints can be a pain)

> Are there other structures that I should be using instead?
>   No - collect your functions into modules but of course use records and abstract data-types for your data.
>
> How do I declare a module?

Have a look at the online docs: Modules (F#) - there you will find everything you need.

Answer (score 4):

What is a module:

A module is compiled down to a static class.  But I think of modules as being analogous to namespaces in C#

there are classes in F# - use

```
 type SomeType(constructor,args) = 
      ....
```

If you have

```
namespace Name
module Mod
....
```

this won't compile - as you know, you can use a few alternatives

```
module Namespace.Module
```

as the first line in the file

or

```
namespace Name
module Mod =
    ....
```